# wso2is key manager feature - automated task or configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We're considering to use the WSO2 IS as a Key Manager for WSO2 API Manager. There's an already [prepackaged version of the WSO2 IS with a Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+with+API+Manager).

it looks ok, the issue is, in our environment there already exists a WSO2 IS installation, and it's not the "prepackaged" version.

From the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0) I see that a KeyManager feature needs to be installed and some configuration updated. I'd like to automate the manual step of installing the KeyManager feature (using any automation tool / script).

**Is there a way to install the Key  Manager feature other than manually from the admin console?** If not then I will ask people managing the IS to deploy the "prepackaged" version, just it may take some time.